# ag-grid is there but completely invisible when css is applied

Tags: meteor, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to put a react ag-grid into meteor, and i've hit what seems to be a css snag, but it's strange enough that i'm not sure and can't get past it.

If I don't include the ag-grid and ag-theme-fresh css files, my data comes in and appears -- all horribly unformatted, of course -- like this:
[image: Unformatted ag-grid with data]

But if I include the two css files, I get what looks like a blank screen, except that everything is there, in grid form, as though all is well, but it's all invisible. Like this:
[image: Formatted ag-grid all invisible]

Here's my code -- can someone help me understand what's going on here?

```
class AdminThings extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onGridReady( params ){

  }

  renderGrid(things) {
    return (
    <div className="ag-theme-fresh"> 
    <AgGridReact 
      id="myGrid"
      rowData={things}
      onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
    >
      {Things.schema._schemaKeys.map((row, index) => {
        return ( <AgGridColumn key={row} field={row}></AgGridColumn> );
      })}
    </AgGridReact>
    </div>
    );
  }  

  render() {
    return( !this.props.loading ? this.renderGrid(this.props.things) : <div></div>);
  }
};

AdminThings.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  things: PropTypes.array
};

export default AdminThings = withTracker(({ match }) => {
  const subHandle = Meteor.subscribe( 'things' );
  const loading = !subHandle.ready();
  let things;
  if ( !loading ) {
    things = Things.find().fetch();
  }
  return {
    loading,
    things: things,
  };
})(AdminThings);
```

I'm not familiar with total invisibility, except when something has opacity 0 on it, and that's not the case here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out from one of ag-grid's examples. By explicitly defining a height and width of the div that contains the AgGridReact component, everything miraculously appears. So, by changing the one line in the example above from this:

```
<div className="ag-theme-fresh">
```

to this:

```
<div style={{height: 400, width: 900, marginTop: 15}} className="ag-theme-fresh">
```

I get the desired result:
[image: ag-grid fixed]